# problem with apt upgrade trying to use do-release-upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I´ve been using my wsl since 2018, but i´ve never updated the version. I installed the wsl form Microsoft store, without the release version, and i wanted to update ubuntu.
I tried using `do-release-upgrade`, but it failed with an error of ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'apt_pkg'

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/do-release-upgrade", line 11, in <module>
from UpdateManager.Core.MetaRelease import MetaReleaseCore
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UpdateManager/Core/MetaRelease.py", line 25, in <module>
import apt
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

so I tried updating apt with `sudo apt update`, and it was the same error of ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg',

```
Fetched 9348 kB in 22s (418 kB/s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

so I tried installing python3 again, with the command
`sudo apt-get install python3-apt --reinstall`
It installed ok, but when i tried `sudo apt update` again it showed the same error.

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_13.x bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/cnf-update-db", line 8, in <module>
from CommandNotFound.db.creator import DbCreator
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/creator.py", line 11, in <module>
import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
Reading package lists... Done
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

How can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: ust download the 20.04 wsl from the microsoft store

Comment: Tried that, but i have some modifications saved that i can't export

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: @Kulfy the output is `/usr/bin/python3: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/python3`

Comment: And what about `file /etc/alternatives/python3`?

Comment: @Kulfy the output is `/etc/alternatives/python3: symbolic link to /usr/bin/python3.7` but i already tried changing the alternative with `update-alternatives --list python` and tried with python 2.7, python 3.7.9 and python 3.8.5

Comment: I don't have 18.04 installed at the moment but IIRC the default Python 3 version on 18.04 was 3.6.5. Do you have that version currently installed? Also, `update-alternatives --list python` doesn't change alternatives. It just lists the available options. Did you mean `--config`?

Comment: @Kulfy Yeah, it was `--config` and no, I don´t have that version of python  installed. I am not even sure the ubuntu version i have is 18.04. I can't check the version of ubuntu I have because it gets the same error

Comment: What is the output of `lsb_release -a; file /usr/bin/python3.6`?